# How can I install xmlwriter?

Tags: php, apache2.4

I've started using a library that requires **xmlwriter** PHP extension, and it seems like it is not installed on my server.

How can I install it?

I tried this:

```
sudo yum install libxml2
```

but the result is:

```
There are no enabled repos.
```

Is there another way to install it, for example using apt-get? Or how can I install it?

Answer (score 7):

I did it with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This confirms **xmlwriter** is installed:

```
php -i | grep "xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

The package manager `yum` is not used on debian distros like Ubuntu. It's used on Fedora and RHEL. :)

What @user838550 wrote should work. If you've got 5.6 running use `sudo apt install php5.6-xml`

Answer (score 0):

I'm running ubuntu 22.04 on my PC and I managed to install the using

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
sudo snap install xmlstarlet
```

and then restarting the server for

```
sudo systemctrl restart nginx.service
```